# background image overflow / image overlap other components

Tags: css, background-image, overlap

this centre logo (background image) is a circle shape. It overlaps the border line on the left side. I tried to apply overflow: hidden, clip, auto on the div as well as the image itself but still does not stop overlapping the line.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/75T7G.png)

I tried overflow: hidden, clip, auto but did not resolve the issue.

```
.centre_logo_container {
  
}

.centre_logo_container.open {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100vh;
  left: 52%;
  top: 43.5%;
}

.centre_logo_container.close {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

.centre_logo {
  height: 270px;
  min-height: 270px;
  max-height: 270px;
  width: 270px;
  max-width: 270px;
  min-width: 270px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-top: 0px;
  padding-top: 0px;
}
```

Comment: add the code you have tried so far.

Comment: overflow: hidden, clip and auto. none of these worked

Comment: no i am saying add the code whatever you have tired so far.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. We're here to help you, but you have to help us to help you. Please take the time to look through [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), particularly the section "Help others reproduce the problem". It would be easier to help if you [create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make a live demo.

Answer (score 1):

You can apply `z-index: 0` on the logo. It should send the logo behind the rest of the elements.